Proving that map from TM to M is an open map.
I am having trouble formalising that $\pi:TM\longrightarrow M$ defined by $\pi(m,v)=m$ is an open map, with M a smooth manifold and TM the tangent manifold of M.
I understand that I need to prove that if $U\subset TM$ then $\pi(U)$ is also open. My intuition says that if U is a set of points from $TM$ $(m,v)$ and that application leaves me with m, the set of points m has to be an open set V in M but I don't know how to formalise this or if this is completely correct.

Since openness is a local property, you can restrict to a chart, and things become obvious ($TM\to M$ is locally trivial).

So if i take the atlas {$\phi_\alpha, U_\alpha$} of TM can I just say that since $\phi(U)$ is open (by definition), the projection map is open? If not, I don't quite yet understand.

It has been edited.

Let's use local triviality of $TM.$
For each $(p,v)\in TM,$  there's an open set $U_p$ with $p\in U_p\subset M$ on which we have $TM$ equals $U_p×\Bbb R^n.$
Now given an open  $V\subset TM$ note that for each $q\in \pi(V),$  we can choose a small enough $U_q$ as above such that $\pi(U_q×\Bbb R^n)=U_q\subset \pi(V).$  Thus $\pi(V)$ is open.
